# How to get into single user mode in Db2?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

**Microsoft SQL Server**

```
ALTER DATABASE baza SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Above command does:

1. Forces all of the users from database.
2. Restricts access to database to all users:

   - except one and only user that has executed the command
   - any other user even super-user can not get access to database
   - even the same user that put database in single user mode but in second connection is restricted to database

**Db2**

```
QUIESCE DATABASE IMMEDIATE
```

1. Forces all users from database.
2. Restricts access to database to all users:

   - except all users with SYSADM, SYSMAINT, DBADM, or SYSCTRL authorities.

Is there *single user* mode in Db2 v11.5/Linux, so only one single user that has put database into single user mode has access to it in one single session?

Comment: No there isn't a single user mode in Db2.

Comment: Have you tried `connect to <dbname> in exclusive mode` ?

Comment: I tried it now. Interesting idea. But it is not truly "single user mode".
Disadvantages: 1. Command does not forces other user from database; 2. Restricts connections to all users except the user with the same userid (this user can connect in multiple sessions); 3. Another db administrator can force this connection from the database and other users can automatically connect to database.

Comment: @folow You may code the desired behavior in the [Connect procedure](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=parameters-connect-proc-connect-procedure-name-database) raising the exception when, say, you have set some flag in a service table (assuming you don't need such a single user mode permanently) + `SELECT 1 FROM TABLE (MON_GET_CONNECTION (NULL, -2)) WHERE APPLICATION_HANDLE <> MON_GET_APPLICATION_HANDLE() LIMIT 1` returns a row.

Answer (score 0):

In our case all users are connecting to database using TCP/IP protocol. I somehow made a work-around by temporally disable TCPIP protocol.

1. Connect to Linux server with SSH.
2. Disabled TCPIP.

   db2set DB2COMM=
3. Stop instance.

   db2stop force
4. Do the task I want to do in "single user" mode.
5. Set back TCPIP and start instance.

   db2set DB2COMM=TCPIP

   db2tart

I know this is not true "single use" mode. Disadvantages:

- if there are multiple databases in instance all databases will lose TCP/IP connections
- if there are local Db2 tasks within Linux itself it will not be blocked
- it is required to coordinate between administrators, so some other admin does not start the database